# What's the difference between rompecabezas and pasatiempo in the context of a (writing) puzzle?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, significado, diferencias-entre-palabras

- What's the difference between `rompecabezas` and `pasatiempo` in the
  context of a puzzle which you write on? (e.g. Word Search, Suduko, Maze etc).
- Can the words be used interchangeably?
- When would you use one word over the other?

---

### Research I have done:

### SpanishDict

SpanishDict primarily [defines `rompecabezas` as a jigsaw puzzle](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/Rompecabezas). However, it does provide a colloquial meaning of something complicated in the sense of a puzzling concept. Neither of these seem to fit directly with Word Search, Suduko, Maze etc, although I guess there would be overlap.

SpanishDict primarily [defines `pasatiempo` as a hobby or past time](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/pasatiempo). But it also provides a meaning of games in a newspaper, which perfectly fits with Word Search, Suduko, Maze etc.

So on the basis of this, I would say that `pasatiempo` is more for newspaper-style puzzles (e.g.Word Search, Suduko, Maze etc). Where as  `rompecabezas` is more for physical puzzles such as jigsaw.

### Word Reference

Word Reference is similar to SpanishDict. `Rompecabezas` is [defined as jigsaw puzzle](https://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=Rompecabezas) or something complicated. `Pasatiempo` is [defined only as hobby](https://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=Pasatiempo). Unlike Spanish Dict, the other meaning is not given.

So this would again suggest that `rompecabezas` is more for physical puzzles (e.g. jigsaw), where as `pasatiempo` is more suited to hobbies.

### Amazon

On Amazon there are several books Word Search Books such as [Sopa De Letras En Español](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08BDVN1WV), [Sopa de Letras: 101 Rompecabezas](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/109272964X), [Supremo Sopa de Letras](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1795549270). All of these use the word `rompecabezas` for puzzle, which seems to be the norm on Amazon. I can only find one book that uses `pasatiempo`.

This seems to be the opposite of SpanishDict and Word Reference. It's very confusing!

---

### Interchangeability

Are the words interchangeable? For example, if I wanted to say `The puzzles all follow the classic word search format.`. Would `rompecabezas` and `pasatiempo` be interchangeable?

E.g.

```
Los pasatiempos siguen el formato clásico de sopa de Letras.
Los rompecabezas siguen el formato clásico de sopa de Letras.
```

---

### Using one word over the other

What about using `pasatiempos` dual meaning of puzzle and hobby. E.g. `Puzzle book 1: hobbies`. If I said `Pasatiempo Libro 1: Pasatiempos e intereses` would it be understood, or would this be a circumstance where only `rompecabezas` could be used?

---

**Notes:**

- I am a beginner learner to Spanish, so I would appreciate simplified
  explanations.
- The questions about Interchangeability and using one over the other,
  are to assist the understanding of the difference between the two
  words, so I would appreciate an answer that makes reference to these
  areas.

Comment: «rompecabezas» needs to be "puzzling" and you are usually **solving** something. «Pasatiempos» it is just that "a pass time" but does not need to be difficult or even needs to solve anything (it could be difficult, but doesn't need to be.)

Comment: rompecabezas is a puzzle, of whatever kind. A pasatiempo is something that allows you to pass the time. **There is no real noun in English for it** but the verb (pass the time) explains it. You pass or kill time by playing a rompecabezas. No, they are not interchangeable at all.

Comment: Un rompecabeza es un TIPO de pasatiempo. A puzzle lets you pass the time or kill time.

Comment: Lambie, "pastime" is a perfectly useful English term and a literal translation for "pasatiempo."  Baseball, for example, used to be called the US's "national pastime." You're right, it has no equivalency with puzzle or any translation of "rompecabeza."

Comment: Just for background the Wikipedia entry for "Rompecabezas" focusses almost entirely on jigsaw puzzles.  However, it mentions Rubik's cube as a famous example.  Here, the mental challenge does not come from fitting the pieces together, as in a jigsaw puzzle.  Rather, it comes from the movement restrictions caused by the inner mechanism of the cube itself.  https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rompecabezas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a "pasatiempo" is a broader concept. In a newspaper a "pasatiempo" could be a game such as a crossword ([crucigrama](https://ast.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crucigrama)), sudoku or word search ([sopa de letras](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sopa_de_letras)) and similar challenges.

You could use "rompecabezas" for such (intellectual) challenges/games. You would be using then the second acception of the word rather than the first one, but I think that *pasatiempo* would be more correct in this context.

> **[rompecabezas](https://dle.rae.es/rompecabezas?m=form)**
>
> 1. m. Juego que consiste en componer determinada figura combinando cierto número de pedazos de madera o cartón, en cada uno de los cuales hay una parte de la figura.

> 2. m. coloq. Problema o acertijo de difícil solución.

As stated in the first description a "rompecabezas" tends to be something like a jigsaw puzzle or other type or puzzle. Probably you could say that a Rubik's cube is a *rompecabezas* and your *pasatiempo* (hobby) is **solving** the *rompecabezas* (puzzle).

Saying that (solving) crosswords or sudokus is your *pasatiempo* is perfectly valid. Calling them *pasatiempos* conveys that there is not much to do with these puzzles (rompecabezas) except for solving them.

As stated, a *pasatiempo* has a boarder meaning, since not all hobbies (pasatiempos) involve solving puzzles.

> **[pasatiempo](https://dle.rae.es/pasatiempo?m=form)**
>
> 1. m. Actividad de diversión o entretenimiento en que se ocupa un rato de ocio.

You could say that knitting or carpentry is a *pasatiempo*, but obviously not a *rompecabezas* (unless you want to convey that there is a particular task that is challenging).

Within your context, "pasatiempo" and "rompecabezas" are pretty interchangeable.

Comment: Thanks! Does this mean they can be used interchangeably. E.g. Would both `Los pasatiempos siguen el formato clásico de sopa de Letras.` and `Los rompecabezas siguen el formato clásico de sopa de Letras.` be correct? Likewise, would `Pasatiempo Libro 1: Pasatiempos e intereses` be understood as a puzzle book about hobbies?

Comment: Yes, I think they are pretty interchangeable and you got it right from your findings in SpanishDict and Wordreference. I don't agree with the first statement, but using one over the other it's just about referring to the hobby or the type of puzzle. I don't think it will matter much one choice over the other because the context will explain that the hobby is solving the puzzles or that this particular set of _pasatiempos_ are _rompecabezas_ (as opposed to other games/challenges. Knitting is a _pasatiempo_ and not a _rompecabezas_ but this distintion wont apply in your context).

Comment: Her context is that a puzzle allows her to pass the time. Very different.

Comment: Right! A puzzle can be a pastime; most are. A pastime can be a puzzle, but only a few are.